# Inconsistency involving Melnibonean dragons

Tags: dragons, continuity, eternal-champion, elric-saga

Various sources (including the Stormbringer wiki) say that the dragons on Melnibone must sleep a hundred years for every day they are awake. However, in the book *Elric of Melniboné* someone points out to Prince Yrkoon the dragons are sleeping after he recently ordered them to burn a fleet from the human country Vilmir. When Yrkoon escapes and abducts Cymoryl, dragons are used in the search for them, and in the volume *Weird of the White Wolf* the dragons are awakened to torch the human fleet as it leaves Irmyrr.

If the dragons have to sleep a century for every day they are awake, how could the latter two events have happened?

Comment: Obviously, they don't use them all at once....

Answer (score 10):

The true answer is that there is an inconsistency.  These books were very much written individually, as much of the fantasy, sci-fi, and horror was written at the time.

While we now have a series of Elric books, they were not initially created as a whole.   Mr Moorcock wrote many similar books with different characters.  Characters that either were popular with readers or that Moorcock himself enjoyed would have additional stories written about them.

If a limit he had established in a previous story was getting in the way of making his current story better, then the limit could be changed, bypassed, or ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Bad answer, the simple and most logical answer is they are DIFFRENT dragons! Just cause you wakeup some to destroy a fleet and then need them again before a 100 years has passed does NOT mean they are the same individual dragons! There are more than a few dragons and you wake 2 or 3 and when you need dragons again, you wake a different few!

Comment: Given that you recognize this is a bad answer, can you turn it into a good one? I recommend taking a look at [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) to see what that constitutes.

Comment: @amflare it's not entirely clear that the answer Tristan thinks is bad is his own.

Comment: It has been a considerable time since I read these books, but I believe each event was understood to be all dragons being awakened.   While it would be logical to use a limited number of dragons for any single event that might require them, nothing in the stories shows that such a constraint was used.

Comment: @Tristan Alexander- except in the beginning of Elric of Melnibone when Dyvim Tvar is chewing out Yrkoon for using the dragons against the Vilmir fleet he said that all the dragons were sleeping.